# delete row with threshold or category and save to multiple CSV in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy

I am a beginner in python. I have big data looks like this:

```
df
Mean       id
0.089394    1
0.389394    2
0.047313    3
0.047313    4
0.767004    5
0.767004    6
0.363154    7
0.363154    8
0.098941    9
1.578785    10
0           11
.....
```

I want to eliminate or delete row mean column data with category below than 0 to 2 (example: >0, >0.1, >0.2, until >2). I used this code:

```
df = df[df.Mean > 0]
```

if I use this code, I have to put many threshold categories every single code. Is there an elegant way to calculate and save to multiple CSV automatically based on each threshold?

for example my desire output for >0

```
df>0
Mean       id
0.089394    1
0.389394    2
0.047313    3
0.047313    4
0.767004    5
0.767004    6
0.363154    7
0.363154    8
0.098941    9
1.578785    10
```

for >0.1

```
df>0.1
Mean       id
0.089394    1
0.389394    2
0.767004    5
0.767004    6
0.363154    7
0.363154    8
1.578785    10
```

and so on

Comment: what is `result.Mean`? is `result` another dataframe?

Comment: forgive me,, the question was edited again

Comment: what happens if you do `df.loc[(df['Mean'] > 0) & (df['Mean']) < 2)].to_csv('PATH_HERE')`

Comment: I got "EOL while scanning string literal"

Comment: oops, I added an extra parenthesis `df.loc[(df['Mean'] > 0) & (df['Mean'] < 2)]`.

Comment: until now, I stiil got [Errno 13] Permission denied:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a function that takes in the mean value and the threshold as the variables:

```py
def helping_func(value, threshold):
    return (value > threshold)
```

Use a `for` loop to perform the conditional check and store into individual csv files:

```py
for i in np.arange(0,21,1): # to import numpy as np
    threshold = i/10 # to overcome floating point inaccuracy
    result_df = df[helping_func(df["Mean"], threshold)]
    csvFileName = "result" + str(i) + ".csv" # name the individual csv files in any format as you deemed appropriate
    result_df.to_csv(csvFileName, sep=",") # sep character at your preference
```

Alternatively, just apply the conditional check inside the `for` loop:

```py
for i in np.arange(0,21,1): # to import numpy as np
    threshold = i/10 # to overcome floating point inaccuracy
    result_df = df[df["Mean"] > threshold]
    csvFileName = "result" + str(i) + ".csv" # name the individual csv files in any format as you deemed appropriate
    result_df.to_csv(csvFileName, sep=",") # sep character at your preference
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. This way is working perfectly. Forgive me, what it means (0,21,1)? if I want to change the threshold, which part should I change? for example again from 0 to 100 with two conditions 1. from 0, 0.1, 0.2-100 . 2. from 0,1,2,3 to 100

Comment: @Arief You may refer to this reference for the numpy.arange() method: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html